# Как осуществить выборку из таблицы по id?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Существуют таблицы recipes И users2recipes.
В users2recipes записываются recipesId и usersId.
Как оформить выборку recipes, где id = recipesId в контроллере?
Не понимаю как это должно выглядеть.
Пробовал так.

```
$id = Yii::$app->user->id;

$favorites = UsersRecipes::find()->where(['usersId' => $id])->all();
$model = Recipes::find()->where(['id' => $favorites->recipesId])->all();

return $this->render('saved', [
'model' => $model,
'favorites' => $favorites,
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам разобрался.
Создал массив recipesId и уже с его элементами сравнил id recipes.

```
$id = Yii::$app->user->id;

$favorites = UsersRecipes::find()->where(['usersId' => $id])->all();

$recipesId = [];

foreach ($favorites as $favorites) {
    $recipesId[] = $favorites->recipesId;
}

$model = Recipes::find()->where(['id' => $recipesId])->all();
```

Comment: внутри цикла точно `$recs[]`? или все таки `$recipesId`. Если `$recipesId` то правильней сделать это дело одним запросом.

Answer (score 1):

Правильней будет сделать через [relation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr).

В Вашем случае в модели UsersRecipes нужно добавить\редактировать метод relations, пример:

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return [
         'recipes'=> [self::HAS_MANY, 'Recipes', 'recipesId']
               ]
    }
```

Теперь для вывода можно использовать созданную нами зависимость:

```
$user = UsersRecipes::find()->with('recipes')->where(['usersId' => $id])->all();
foreach ($user->recipes as $recipe) {
//do some here
}
```